# How do you do a contains query using the MongoDB node.js driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to do a search on items that contain a certain substring, but I'm getting no results back (even though I know the data is right for the query, including case):

```
collection.find({name: "/.*" + keyword + ".*/"}).toArray(function(err, items)
```

Should that not match everything that contains the keyword? It just returns an empty object.

I'm just using the regular MongoDB driver in an ExpressJS app.

Comment: you can only pass objects into find, not a string. and it should be a regex anyways, not a strong.

Comment: Good catch. I actually do pass an object in my code, I just typed up a simple example of what I was doing here. It's been fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to build a regular expression first should try something like this:

```
var regex = RegExp("/.*" + keyword + ".*/")
```

Then pass in the variable to the query.  I generally find it easier to do the query as a variable and pass that in:

```
var query = { FieldToSearch: new RegExp('^' + keyword) };
collection.find(query).toArray(...)
```

I've included the regex as a left rooted regex to take advantage of indexes (always recommended if possible for performance).  For more take a look here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions

Comment: Look at the top example. They don't build a RegExp object. Also, I've seen the carrot being used like a .* a few times now. Is the carrot not a negation operator? I would think ^keyword would match everything that isn't the keyword.

Comment: no, the ^ in a regular expression is the start of line anchor, not a negation, it basically just means if it "starts with"

Comment: A caret only negates inside a character class: [^aeiou]

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this

```
    keyword = "text_to_search";
    collection.find({name: {$Regex: keyword, $options:$i }})
```

I used i $i make the query case insensitive but u can use other options too

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var keyword = req.params.keywords;
var regex = RegExp(".*" + keyword + ".*");
Note.find({noteBody: regex, userID: userID})
```

Comment: I got the keywords from the request parameters and I want to search from the noteBody with these keywords, now the keywords is a variable. If you want to put a variable in the database find, the format must be var regex = RegExp("." + keyword + "."). Hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: @KelciHung : Please add that in answer section.

Answer (score 0):

I got the keywords from the request parameters and I want to search from the noteBody with these keywords, now the keywords is a variable. If you want to put a variable in the database find, the format must be var regex = RegExp("." + keyword + "."). Hope this helps. Thanks